# Sending AT Command for sms to arduinoShield

Tags: gsm

i have a Arduino GSMShield and I want to send SMS.
When the module try to connecting to the network, it print AT+CREG?
Dont know why cause there's no serial.println for this

```
int8_t answer;
int onModulePin= 2;
char aux_str[30];

//Change here your data
const char pin[]="";
//const char phone_number[]=" number OK";
const char sms_text[]="Test-Arduino-Hello World";  

void setup(){

  pinMode(onModulePin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);    

  Serial.println("Starting..");

//  power_on();

  delay(3000);

  //sets the PIN code
  sprintf(aux_str, "AT+CPIN=%s", pin);
  sendATcommand(aux_str, "OK", 2000);
  
  delay(3000);

  Serial.println("Connecting to the network..");

  while( (sendATcommand("AT+CGREG?", "+CREG= 0,1", 500) || 
    sendATcommand("AT+CGREG?", "+CREG: 0,5", 500)) == 0 );
  

  Serial.print("Setting SMS mode..");
  sendATcommand("AT+CMGF=1", "OK", 1000);    // sets the SMS mode to text
  Serial.println("Sending SMS");

  sprintf(aux_str,"AT+CMGS=\"%s\"", phone_number);
  answer = sendATcommand(aux_str, ">", 2000);    // send the SMS number
  if (answer == 1)
  {                                                                                                      
    Serial.println(sms_text);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    answer = sendATcommand("", "OK", 20000);
    if (answer == 1)
    {
      Serial.print("Sent ");    
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.print("error ");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print("error ");
    Serial.println(answer, DEC);
  }

}


void loop(){

}

void power_on(){

  uint8_t answer=0;
  Serial.println("2/2..");

  // checks if the module is started
  answer = sendATcommand("AT", "OK", 2000);
  if (answer == 0)
  {
    // power on pulse
    Serial.println("2*3..");
    digitalWrite(onModulePin,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(onModulePin,LOW);

    // waits for an answer from the module
    while(answer == 0){     // Send AT every two seconds and wait for the answer
      answer = sendATcommand("AT", "OK", 2000);    
        Serial.println("3*2..");

    }
  }

}

int8_t sendATcommand(const char* ATcommand, const char* expected_answer, unsigned int timeout){

  uint8_t x=0,  answer=0;
  char response[100];
  unsigned long previous;

  memset(response, '\0', 100);    // Initialice the string

  delay(100);

  while( Serial.available() > 0) Serial.read();    // Clean the input buffer

  Serial.println(ATcommand);    // Send the AT command 


    x = 0;
  previous = millis();

  // this loop waits for the answer
  do{
    // if there are data in the UART input buffer, reads it and checks for the answer
    if(Serial.available() != 0){    
      response[x] = Serial.read();
      x++;
      // check if the desired answer is in the response of the module
      if (strstr(response, expected_answer) != NULL)    
      {
        answer = 1;
      }
    }
    // Waits for the answer with time out
  }
  while((answer == 0) && ((millis() - previous) < timeout));    

  return answer;
}
```